# (completed) My coding is having an issue where it cannot accept any space in the string, and I have to use scanf

Tags: c

(Completed/solved)
basically what the tittle says. I've been looking up solutions because im using scanf, the problem is if I don't use scanf all my code just dies, and I've been trying the %^\n and that just makes it worse. here is my code:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 struct employee
{
char name[20];
float oldSalary;
float rate;
float raise;
float newSalary;
};

int main(void)
{
int numE, placeholder;


 printf("How many Employees: ");
scanf("%d",&numE);


float totalOldsal,totalRaise,totalNewsal=0;

 struct employee names[20];
 for(placeholder=1; placeholder <= numE ; placeholder++)
 {
    printf("\nEnter the employee's name: ",placeholder+1);
    scanf("%s[^\n]",names[placeholder].name);

    printf("\nEnter salary:", placeholder+1);
    scanf("%f",&names[placeholder].oldSalary);

    printf("Enter rate:", placeholder+1);
    scanf("%f",&names[placeholder].rate);

    names[placeholder].raise = names[placeholder].rate * names[placeholder].oldSalary /100;
    names[placeholder].newSalary = names[placeholder].oldSalary + names[placeholder].raise;
    totalOldsal += names[placeholder].oldSalary;
    totalRaise += names[placeholder].raise;
    totalNewsal += names[placeholder].newSalary;

    printf("\nEmployee's Name       : %s", names[placeholder].name);
    printf("\nSalary                : %.2f", names[placeholder].oldSalary);
    printf("\nRate                  : %.1f%%", names[placeholder].rate);
    printf("\nRaise                 : %.2f", names[placeholder].raise);
    printf("\nNew salary            : %.2f\n", names[placeholder].newSalary);

}
printf("\nTotal salary          : %f", totalOldsal);
printf("\nTotal Raise           : %f", totalRaise);
printf("\nTotal New Salary      : %f", totalNewsal);
```

}

---

Thank you all! I ended up using scanf(" %19[^\n]",names[placeholder].name);

Comment: The leading space recommended by @user3121023 before the format specifier is to filter whitespace from tne input. The `%s` and `%d` and `%f` formats do that automatically, but `%c` and `%n` and `%[]` do not. Note that your `%s[^\n]` is an incorrect hybrid of `%s` and `%[...]`

Comment: If you solved the problem yourself then either a) delete the question or b) write your solution as an answer and accept it. Both is better than keeping the question open and writing the answer into the question.